# yii2 always redirect to frontend/web

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

When i want to access to backend yii2 always redirect me to frontend.
Example:
I have installed the yii2-user (dektrium) module in frontend and backend and yii2-admin (mdm) module only in backend . And when i want to acess to 
`http://localhost/american_eshop/yii-application/frontend/web/**user/admin/index**"`
 yii2 in the first place accessing to this route and after redirect me to `"http://localhost/american_eshop/yii-application/frontend/web/"`.

I.E. i can get access to resourse but it always redirect me and i cannot undestand where i am in my site.

Sorry for my poor english...

backend cofigs:

main.php

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
'id' => 'app-backend',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'modules' => [],
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'dektrium\user\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager'
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],

    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
],



'params' => $params,
];
```

main-local:

```
<?php

$config = [
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'QuXcvHHNSiT3mEGgBln9c85IYF7uVkoU',
    ],
],
'modules' => [

    'user' => [
        'class'    => 'backend\modules\user\Module',
        'viewPath' => '@dektrium/user/views',
        'enableUnconfirmedLogin' => true,
        'confirmWithin' => 21600,
        'cost' => 14,
        'admins' => ['Admin']
    ],

]
];

if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
// configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
$config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
$config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

$config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
$config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}

return $config;
```

frontend:

main:

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
'id' => 'app-frontend',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'dektrium\user\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager'
    ],

    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],

    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
],


'params' => $params,
];
```

main-local:

```
<?php

$config = [
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'xlEFSbBB0pjvAJHtEOfY6r5BhDOTIAtB',
    ],
],
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class'    => 'frontend\modules\user\Module',
        'viewPath' => '@dektrium/user/views',
        'enableUnconfirmedLogin' => true,
        'confirmWithin' => 21600,
        'cost' => 14,
        'admins' => ['Admin']
    ],
],

];

if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
// configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
$config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
$config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

$config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
$config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}

return $config;
```

Comment: I have resolved my problem. The problem was due to uncorrect config yii2-user.

Comment: Please outline your configuration problem with yii2-user as an answer and accept it. This will mark the question as solved so that it doesn't appear in the unanswered section.